# Postmaster doesn't email on bulk status change

Tags: postmaster

I have several status change parcels that work great both from Safecracker forms as well as single edits on the cp, however if I bulk edit the entries to change multiple entries status' the status changes parcel are not triggered.

Any ideas?

-Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it was an oversight when I first built Postmaster, but this functionality is currently not supported. Postmaster is just triggered by the entry_submission_end hook, not the bulk update.It could easily be added, but currently it's not available.

I will definitely add this to the list of things to support in the next release, which is v1.3. I don't have any ETA available for this release, so email support[at]objectivehtml.com if you have a tight deadline and we might be able to work out something.

The real problem I see is that the native EE hook doesn't pass much data. So you would have to rely on the POST data and loop through the entry_id's.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - I didn't realize how the hook was setup, its not vital to my current workflow but would be a HUGE plus for the users who will be using it.  

Thanks for the quick reply. I look forward to the updates that will include the bonus feature.

Comment: +1 for this feature. Took me a while to realise why the parcel wasn't working until I figured out it doesn't trigger on bulk status update.